# Inferred Lifetime of a &mut self in Rustonomicon Example

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the Rustonomicon, there is a discussion of the limitations of the current Rust lifetimes system (https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html).

The following example is given as something that does not compile due to how lifetimes are inferred (with artificial lifetime annotations):

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn mutate_and_share<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a Self { &'a *self }
    fn share<'a>(&'a self) {}
}

fn main() {
    'b: {
        let mut foo: Foo = Foo;
        'c: {
            let loan: &'c Foo = Foo::mutate_and_share::<'c>(&'c mut foo);
            'd: {
                Foo::share::<'d>(&'d foo);
            }
            println!("{:?}", loan);
        }
    }
}
```

The nomicon's explanation is that the signature of `mutate_and_share()` forces the lifetime of the mutable borrow of `foo` to be `'c`, which then conflicts with the immutable reference required by the `share()` call, the lifetime `'d` of which is subordinate to `'c`.

*I am confused about why this does not conflict with the immutable borrow at the end of `mutate_and_share()`.* Namely, the following code compiles:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn mutate_and_share(&mut self) -> &Self { &*self }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo;
    let loan = foo.mutate_and_share();
    println!("{:?}", loan);
}
```

Yet the previous discussion seems to imply that the mutable borrow's lifetime should still extend until the `println!()` call, meaning that it coexists with the immutable `loan` borrow. In my understanding this should then violate the "one mutable or multiple immutable borrows" rule for the same object `foo`. I would appreciate if someone could explain what is happening here in greater detail.

Comment: "meaning that it coexists with the immutable `loan` borrow." You seem to be a bit confused here. Your code works because you get an immutable borrow with `mutate_and_share`, and store that in `loan`. You then print `foo` **through** the `loan` borrow, so there's only ever one reference to the value.